# Contract too large

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging

I am sure this has already been answered but I could not find a clear answer. I get the following error:

Contract creation initialization returns data with length of more than 24576 bytes. The deployment will likely fails.

I use Remix for compiling. How can I find out how long the code is? How is it calculated? Thanks!

Comment: Please show the contract.

Comment: I would recommend restructure your code and use more library to contain logic code

Comment: One clarifying point - the code is not specially long but the compiled code hits the size limit. The question I am looking to answer is how I can check on compile how large the " data length" is?

Comment: Also, @Miao ZhiCheng - what do you mean by use libraries to contain logic code. How would that work? Thanks!

Comment: I think he wantedto say that you should split your contract into multiple ones.

Comment: Hi guys, what happens if Philip uses inherited contracts instead of one contract? @MiaoZhiCheng

Comment: @maxpeinas I get the idea of breaking one large contract into smaller contracts, but how does it work with transaction costs and execution? Specifically I don’t want to have confirm a metamask transaction for each part of the contract as it then becomes unusable. I would appreciate your feedback. Many thanks.